# How to wrap all elements in each container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to wrapAll divs that are children of li except the div with class A. Also need to keep them in their parent li's.

Current html:

```
<ul class="container">
 <li>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
 </li>

 <li>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Desired output:

```
<ul class="container">
 <li>
  <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="wrapped">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
   </div>
 </li>

 <li>
   <div class="a"></div>
     <div class="wrapped">
       <div class="b"></div>
       <div class="c"></div>
     </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thought this code would do it but it's not working. I would like to use a variable to define the selected divs:

```
var selected = $("li").children().not(".a");
$(selected).each(function() {
    $(selected).wrapAll($("<div class='wrapped'></div>"));
});
```

Comment: Do you want to change the classes too? from `b`, `b` to `b`, `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each `li` and then wrap it's children which don't have class `a`.
`wrapAll` will wrap all possible matched elements, so it'll also wrap the matched elements from other `li`.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).children().not('.a').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped"></div>');
});
```

```css
.wrapped {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```